# Building graphs based on pairs of connected vertices

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

I need to check how many separate graphs would be created where "n lines contains pairs of positive integers, where each pair identifies a connection between two vertices in a graph. ".
Suppose we have 3 pairs: [4 3], [1 4], [5 6].
The answer will be 2, because [4 3]&[1 4] will merge into one graph: [1 3 4] and the 2nd one is [5 6].
If we add one more pair: [4 3], [1 4], [5 6], [4 6], the answer will be 1 (only 1 graph: [1 3 4 5 6] are connected).

I managed to solve the problem in Java, but it's not efficient, and for more than 10000+ pairs it works terribly slow. The code looks more or less that:

```
    Set<Pair> connectionsSet;
    HashSet<TreeSet<Integer>> createdConnections;
    
    public void createGraphs() {
        for (Pair pair : connectionsSet) {
            boolean foundLeft = false, foundRight = false;
            for (TreeSet<Integer> singleSet : createdConnections) {
                if (singleSet.contains(pair.getLeft())) foundLeft = true;
                if (singleSet.contains(pair.getRight())) foundRight = true;
            }
            if (!foundLeft && !foundRight)
                addNewGraph(pair);
            else if (foundLeft && !foundRight)
                addToExistingGraph(pair, Constants.LEFT);
            else if (!foundLeft && foundRight)
                addToExistingGraph(pair, Constants.RIGHT);
            else if (foundLeft && foundRight)
                mergeGraphs(pair);
        }
    }

    private void addNewGraph(Pair pair) {
        createdConnections.add(new TreeSet<>(pair.asList()));
    }

    private void addToExistingGraph(Pair pair, String side) {
        for (TreeSet<Integer> singleSet : createdConnections) {
            if (side.equals(Constants.LEFT) && singleSet.contains(pair.getLeft()))
                singleSet.add(pair.getRight());
            if (side.equals(Constants.RIGHT) && singleSet.contains(pair.getRight()))
                singleSet.add(pair.getLeft());
        }
    }

    private void mergeGraphs(Pair pair) {
        Optional<TreeSet<Integer>> leftSetOptional = getOptional(pair.getLeft());
        Optional<TreeSet<Integer>> rightSetOptional = getOptional(pair.getRight());

        if (leftSetOptional.isPresent() && rightSetOptional.isPresent()){
            TreeSet<Integer> leftSet = leftSetOptional.get();
            TreeSet<Integer> rightSet = rightSetOptional.get();

            rightSet.addAll(leftSet);

            createdConnections.removeIf(singleSet -> singleSet.contains(pair.getLeft()));
            createdConnections.removeIf(singleSet -> singleSet.contains(pair.getRight()));
            createdConnections.add(rightSet);

        }
    }
```

How can I improve the performance? I'm not asking for a ready-made solution, but maybe there is an algorithm that I don't know about that could significantly speed it up?

Comment: Do you only need the count?

Comment: Yes, I only need the count

Comment: And do you have all the edges (Pairs) at the start? Or do you need to maintain the count while adding more edges?

Comment: Yes, I do have it. I created a file with random 20.000 pairs, (in range 0 - 50000) to see how long will it take, but it took more than 5 minutes)

Comment: You are finding the number of components in a graph.  This is a well known problem that can be solved by using depth first searching.

Comment: Here is some C++ code using DFS to find number of components in a graph. https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/3d4849b228831fa58f5939a4640bf7f8e6bff399/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L805-L857

Comment: https://github.com/mionsek/LSN-Tasks/tree/master

Here is my full code, this is Task no. 3

Comment: LargeTest seems more likely

Comment: Are the vertex numbers always 1 to n?

Comment: Yes, these are random numbers from 1 to n. And yes, it is LargeTest.txt. Sorry for that

Comment: Slightly modified your data file https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/main/dat/mionsekLargeTest.txt and ran it on my code.  Time taken 12 mins.  So you time of 5 mins on this data set is fairly good.

Comment: Look for algorithms to find connected components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get the count of connected components, you can use a disjoint set. This is a simple implementation assuming input as a `List` of edges.

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> parent;
int find(int x) {
    int p = parent.getOrDefault(x, x);
    if (p != x) p = find(p);
    parent.put(x, p);
    return p;
}
public int numConnectedComponents(List<Pair> edges) {
    parent = new HashMap<>();
    for (var e : edges) {
        int lPar = find(e.getLeft()), rPar = find(e.getRight());
        parent.put(lPar, rPar);
    }
    int comps = 0;
    for (var k : parent.keySet())
        if (find(k) == k) ++comps;
    return comps;
}
```

If the number of nodes (`n`) is known and we can assume all node labels are integers between `1` and `n`, we can optimize by using an array instead of a `Map` and keeping track of the number of connected components while adding edges.

```java
int[] parent;
int find(int x) {
    return x == parent[x] ? x : (parent[x] = find(parent[x]));
}
public int numConnectedComponents(int nodes, List<Pair> edges) {
    parent = new int[nodes + 1];
    int comps = 0;
    for (var e : edges) {
        if (parent[e.getLeft()] == 0) {
            parent[e.getLeft()] = e.getLeft();
            ++comps;
        }
        if (parent[e.getRight()] == 0) {
            parent[e.getRight()] = e.getRight();
            ++comps;
        }
        int lPar = find(e.getLeft()), rPar = find(e.getRight());
        if (lPar != rPar) {
            parent[lPar] = rPar;
            --comps;
        }
    }
    return comps;
}
```

Comment: This takes much less than one second to run the large test case (on my machine).

Comment: Impressive.  Can you provide some sort of documentation for your code to explain how it works?

Comment: @ravenspoint See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure The average time complexity of each individual `find` operation is the inverse Ackermann function applied to the number of nodes.

Comment: That is really impressive. Thank you!

Comment: @Mio Happy to help. The code can be further optimized by using an array instead of a `Map` when the number of nodes is known.

Comment: @Unmitigated - I am also wondering if counting separate components wouldn't be faster using stream.distinct:
return Math.toIntExact(parent.values().stream().distinct().count());

But also, if we assume that we know the number of pairs, i.e. 5 - how can it help?

Comment: @Mio The values in `parent` aren't necessarily the latest ones, so counting those wouldn't be correct. I've updated my answer to show a more optimized version with the assumption of what the node labels are.